# Returning a LPWSTR& foo to a function

Tags: c++, mfc

This point will not work. How to fix it. I understand that the CStrings leave the stack after the call to the function. are the any types of strings i C++ std:strings etc. Thats behave as C# strings. How I get it to work?

```
void Dialog1::GetOrderingKey(LPWSTR& lpOrderingKey)
{
   CString OrderingKey;
   m_Result.GetWindowText(OrderingKey);
  lpOrderingKey = OrderingKey.GetBuffer(0);
}

  LPWSTR lpOrderingKey;
  GetOrderingKey(lpOrderingKey);

  int returnValue = lpfnDllOrderingCodeDataW(lpSerialNumber, lpOrderingKey, data, _countof(data));
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

One straight forward and simplest way would be to declare it static.

```
void Dialog1::GetOrderingKey(LPWSTR& lpOrderingKey)
{
   static CString OrderingKey;
```

Comment: Then what happens if you call `GetOrderingKey()` again? This is a __very__ dangerous solution.

Comment: Better that you do not presume that you know what I do or do not know! Returning a reference to a static variable is a poor solution, and the correct solution is __not__ difficult.

Comment: @AAT "This is a very dangerous solution" Could you please cite a case...It would be a great for me too.

Comment: Calls to this function set a pointer (`LPWSTR` == `wchar_t *`) to point to the contents of `OrderingKey`. Unless the caller then knows to copy the information to a buffer of his own (like a `CString`...) then a second call __could__ change what that pointer is pointing to. That's an accident waiting to happen.

Comment: This is from official documentation of CString.GetBuffer(0)..."You cannot safely modify this buffer, because its size is undetermined." That's why I said it's not the problem in this case...

Comment: You are missing the point, and it's not getting better. Returning the value from `GetBuffer()` to a caller who will do who-knows-what with it is a very specific `CString` danger: it's not that the caller __cannot__ modify the (contents of) the buffer - but he certainly cannot do so __safely__! But the objection I raised in the first place is to the idea that returning a reference to a `static` variable is a good way for a function to return a value. I am done now, end of thread.

Comment: Add the fact that he's casting something that is const (GetBuffer() ) to something that is not (LPWSTR&).  It's a horrible "answer".  Michael Burr has the correct solution.

Comment: I don't like this either. Nobody who can see the implementation can know how long the pointer is valid. Because there is no need at all to return a pointer when it is possible to return a CString object. Also why should the string persist over the lifetime of the outer class? Why should this function return an old value, when functions are called in a wrong sequence...?

Answer (score 3):

Just return a CString from `GetOrderingKey()`:

```
CString Dialog1::GetOrderingKey()
{
   CString OrderingKey;
   m_Result.GetWindowText(OrderingKey);
   return OrderingKey;
}

CString ordering_key = GetOrderingKey();

int returnValue = lpfnDllOrderingCodeDataW(lpSerialNumber, (LPCWSTR) ordering_key, data, _countof(data));
```

Comment: This is the right solution. `CString` is designed to be used as if it was a first-class object, and MS have done (most of) the hard work for you. They can be efficiently passed into and returned from functions in most cases.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acttytz3.aspx